# Finding Min/Max Date with List Comprehension in Python

Tags: python, date, list-comprehension

So I have this list:

```
snapshots = ['2014-04-05',
        '2014-04-06',
        '2014-04-07',
        '2014-04-08',
        '2014-04-09']
```

I would like to find the earliest date using a list comprehension.

Heres what I have now,

```
earliest_date = snapshots[0]
earliest_date = [earliest_date for snapshot in snapshots if earliest_date > snapshot]
```

When I print the earliest date, I expect an empty array back since all the values after the first element of the list are already greater than the first element, but I WANT a single value.

Here's the original code just to signify i know how to find the min date value:

```
for snapshot in snapshots:
    if earliest_date > snapshot:
        earliest_date = snapshot
```

Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: If you need *one* value, then a list comprehension is *the wrong tool*

Comment: So i should just stick to what I'm currently doing?

Comment: `earliest_date = min(snapshots)`?!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just use `min()` or `max()` to find the earliest or latest dates:

```
earliest_date = min(snapshots)
lastest_date = max(snapshots)
```

Of course, if your list of dates is already sorted, use:

```
earliest_date = snapshots[0]
lastest_date = snapshots[-1]
```

Demo:

```
>>> snapshots = ['2014-04-05',
...         '2014-04-06',
...         '2014-04-07',
...         '2014-04-08',
...         '2014-04-09']
>>> min(snapshots)
'2014-04-05'
```

Generally speaking, a list comprehension should only be used to build lists, not as a general loop tool. That's what `for` loops are for, really.

Comment: For the OP (I know Martijn knows all about this) - this works because the default sort order for strings of equal lengths of digits is lowest to highest. In cases where the lexical ordering of the values isn't the desired ordering, such as for dates expressed in formats like `'April 6, 2014'` you can provide a `key` function to tell Python how to calculate a comparable value from the input. The fact that the natural ordering of dates in YYYY-MM-DD is what string sorting gives you is a reason it's a good choice.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper: Good point, but it's also worth mentioning that the simplest key function for (non-ISO-format) dates is usually something like `datetime.datetime.strptime` (with a format `partial`ed into it) or other similar way to convert them into actual date objects that know how to compare to each other. (Because many people try to write functions that parse and rearrange the date string manually, and there are so many ways to get that wrong and no reason to try…)

Comment: @abarnert: note that you cannot actually use `partial()` on `datetime.datetime.strptime()` as the format is the *second* positional argument and the C method doesn't accept keyword arguments.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I thought `datetime` was ArgClinic-ified in 3.4, but it looks like you're right. So make that a "with a format `lambda`'d into it".

Comment: @abarnert: A pure-python wrapper now exists, but no arg-clinic handling just yet!

Comment: @MartijnPieters: If you actually take a look at it, the pure-Python wrapper gets overwritten by the C implementation. But if it didn't, it's mostly a complete implementation, not a wrapper, except for a couple functions. But [`strptime`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Lib/datetime.py#l1590) is one of them. But that C function in turn wraps the pure-Python module [`_strptime`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Lib/_strptime.py). Crazy.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> snapshots = ['2014-04-05',
        '2014-04-06',
        '2014-04-07',
        '2014-04-08',
        '2014-04-09']

>>> min(snapshots)
2014-04-05
```

You can use the [`min`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min) function.

However, this assumes that your date is formatted YYYY-MM-DD, because you have strings in your list.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any issue while sorting the list you can convert the list elements to date and find the max/min of it

```
from dateutil import parser
snapshots = ['2014-04-05',
        '2014-04-06',
        '2014-04-07',
        '2014-04-08',
        '2014-04-09']

snapshots = [parser.parse(i).date() for i in snapshots ]

max_date = max(snapshots )
min_date = min(snapshots )
print(max_date)
print(min_date)
```