# How can I find most recent time from a datetime object in string format

Tags: python, datetime

so I have this nested dictionary consisting of either twitter or reddit posts, with each posts id or url as the inner key, and the datetime in string format in the value.

```
{'reddit': {'my6vne': '2021-04-25 16:00:02',
        'my7uar': '2021-04-25 17:00:02',
        'my9i47': '2021-04-25 18:34:09',
        'myhq5w': '2021-04-26 01:10:37',
        'myioia': '2021-04-26 01:57:58',
        'myiout': '2021-04-26 01:58:25',
        'myjhtj': '2021-04-26 02:38:51',
        'myndga': '2021-04-26 06:16:45',
        'myo6x3': '2021-04-26 07:04:48'},
 'twitter': {'https://twitter.com/twitter/statuses/1386540140068102146': '2021-04-26 '
                                                                     '04:38:24',
         'https://twitter.com/twitter/statuses/1386541987210223618': '2021-04-26 '
                                                                     '04:45:45',
         'https://twitter.com/twitter/statuses/1386542478656827394': '2021-04-26 '
                                                                     '04:47:42',
         'https://twitter.com/twitter/statuses/1386544375086321674': '2021-04-26 '
                                                                     '04:55:14',
         'https://twitter.com/twitter/statuses/1386544515964571648': '2021-04-26 '
                                                                     '04:55:48'}}
```

Basically, I want to loop through the dictionary, check all the datetime values (which again are strings), and fetch the most recent one, relative to the current time. How would I go about doing this, as the datetime values are strings?

Comment: What did you try so far? You can convert to `datetime` with `strptime` and compare or, as the per the format used, you can simply use alphanumeric comparison.

Comment: just the string comparison works in your case, you don't need to convert the dates

Comment: BTW, what should happen to timestamps in the future? You don't need to work with the current time at all, unless you need to handle timestamps from the future specially.

Comment: Well, the objects were converted to strings from datetime objects, because the datetime objects formatted very weird upon adding them to the dictionary. For example, '2021-04-26 07:04:48' would format as 'datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 26, 7, 4, 48)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out for converting string to a datetime object
https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-date-in-python

How about you create an object of the current datetime and using the delta method find the difference and choose the minimum value?
More here: [Finding Min/Max Date with List Comprehension in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25002600/finding-min-max-date-with-list-comprehension-in-python/25002652)

Comment: You don't need the delta; the most recent will be the largest one

Comment: This seems like a great solution. My goal, just to mention, is to make a newsfeed timeline, and display the newest posts first. So this would provide a solution to finding the difference in post creation time from the present time. Then I can order the posts as such. Thanks!